# Why is my main controller not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I am brand new to codeigniter but I have been a PHP developer for years.

A client of mine has a exciting codeigniter site that was developed my another developer and I'm trying to set up a dev server to work on the site.

I can load the index.php in views if i go to this url

http://102.236.250.217/app/views/nycity/

But none of the header/footers or css are working
I feel like my controller "class Nycity extends MY_Controller" is not working what could be the cause of this?

This is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]  

<Files "index.php">
 AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>
```

Answer (score 1):

Read [codeigniter's user guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide), learn directory structure, it's MVC. Find where your index.php file is and point domain there.

The rest is magic. Good luck!

P.s. MY_Controller should be located inside application/core according to the rules.

Comment: Turns out I was missing the system folder and index.php file both were not included when the files were sent to me.

Comment: System folder is very important ;) Regards

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to check your route default controller, you should find routes.php in config folder, and this what you should write in:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'your_default_controller';
```

Depending on your description, it should be like this

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'app';
```

And in your app controller should load the "nycity" view